# Copying a file and installing apache via Ansible shows OK but not there when logged into remote server

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am new to Ansible and would appreciate some help understanding why this playbook seems to execute OK but when I login to the remote host, the file isn't there and apache cannot be started.

Here is the playbook:

```
---
- name: Setup webservers
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: copy test
      sudo: yes
      copy: src=/etc/ansible/app/test  dest=/

    - name: install Apache
      sudo: yes
      yum: name=httpd state=present
```

Here is the output:

```
root@ip-172-31-19-255 app]# ansible-playbook -vvv test.yml

PLAY [Setup webservers] *******************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
<172.31.24.166> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<172.31.5.165> REMOTE_MODULE setup
<172.31.5.165> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-268185556939980 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-268185556939980']
<172.31.24.166> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-101316942599470 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-101316942599470']
<172.31.5.165> PUT /tmp/tmpCIgcvv TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-268185556939980/setup
<172.31.5.165> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-268185556939980/setup; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-268185556939980/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
<172.31.24.166> PUT /tmp/tmpAhOtGk TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-101316942599470/setup
<172.31.24.166> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-101316942599470/setup; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.58-101316942599470/ >/dev/null 2>&1']
ok: [172.31.5.165]
ok: [172.31.24.166]

TASK: [copy test] *************************************************************
<172.31.5.165> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'rc=flag; [ -r /test ] || rc=2; [ -f /test ] || rc=1; [ -d /test ] && rc=3; python -V 2>/dev/null || rc=4; [ x"$rc" != "xflag" ] && echo "${rc} "/test && exit 0; (python -c \'import hashlib; BLOCKSIZE = 65536; hasher = hashlib.sha1();\nafile = open("\'/test\'", "rb")\nbuf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)\nwhile len(buf) > 0:\n\thasher.update(buf)\n\tbuf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)\nafile.close()\nprint(hasher.hexdigest())\' 2>/dev/null) || (python -c \'import sha; BLOCKSIZE = 65536; hasher = sha.sha();\nafile = open("\'/test\'", "rb")\nbuf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)\nwhile len(buf) > 0:\n\thasher.update(buf)\n\tbuf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)\nafile.close()\nprint(hasher.hexdigest())\' 2>/dev/null) || (echo \'0 \'/test)']
<172.31.24.166> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'rc=flag; [ -r /test ] || rc=2; [ -f /test ] || rc=1; [ -d /test ] && rc=3; python -V 2>/dev/null || rc=4; [ x"$rc" != "xflag" ] && echo "${rc} "/test && exit 0; (python -c \'import hashlib; BLOCKSIZE = 65536; hasher = hashlib.sha1();\nafile = open("\'/test\'", "rb")\nbuf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)\nwhile len(buf) > 0:\n\thasher.update(buf)\n\tbuf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)\nafile.close()\nprint(hasher.hexdigest())\' 2>/dev/null) || (python -c \'import sha; BLOCKSIZE = 65536; hasher = sha.sha();\nafile = open("\'/test\'", "rb")\nbuf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)\nwhile len(buf) > 0:\n\thasher.update(buf)\n\tbuf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)\nafile.close()\nprint(hasher.hexdigest())\' 2>/dev/null) || (echo \'0 \'/test)']
<172.31.5.165> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.89-213853778271951 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.89-213853778271951']
<172.31.24.166> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.9-233414769988070 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.9-233414769988070']
<172.31.5.165> PUT /tmp/tmp6ejI0a TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.89-213853778271951/file
<172.31.5.165> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=twunfaumexxymoemhcbdsgwtgvhfstjt] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-twunfaumexxymoemhcbdsgwtgvhfstjt; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.89-213853778271951/file; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.89-213853778271951/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''
<172.31.24.166> PUT /tmp/tmpxpX_zM TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.9-233414769988070/file
<172.31.24.166> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=unwvfdmsujhcmoalkeqjhglkhuzbcqcs] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-unwvfdmsujhcmoalkeqjhglkhuzbcqcs; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.9-233414769988070/file; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547006.9-233414769988070/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''
ok: [172.31.5.165] => {"changed": false, "checksum": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", "dest": "/test", "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0664", "owner": "root", "path": "/test", "size": 0, "state": "file", "uid": 0}
ok: [172.31.24.166] => {"changed": false, "checksum": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", "dest": "/test", "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0664", "owner": "root", "path": "/test", "size": 0, "state": "file", "uid": 0}

TASK: [install Apache] ********************************************************
<172.31.5.165> REMOTE_MODULE yum name=httpd state=present
<172.31.5.165> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.04-58359634351509 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.04-58359634351509']
<172.31.24.166> REMOTE_MODULE yum name=httpd state=present
<172.31.24.166> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.05-80567519499784 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.05-80567519499784']
<172.31.5.165> PUT /tmp/tmpN8TP3c TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.04-58359634351509/yum
<172.31.5.165> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=quaahxohwbrzkqkbezturfziaggexqqn] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-quaahxohwbrzkqkbezturfziaggexqqn; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python -tt /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.04-58359634351509/yum; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.04-58359634351509/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''
<172.31.24.166> PUT /tmp/tmpdtc7hX TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.05-80567519499784/yum
<172.31.24.166> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=cdasbsyfzpxxjubjsrchidaxvqblhmfx] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-cdasbsyfzpxxjubjsrchidaxvqblhmfx; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python -tt /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.05-80567519499784/yum; rm -rf /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445547007.05-80567519499784/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''
ok: [172.31.24.166] => {"changed": false, "msg": "", "rc": 0, "results": ["httpd-2.2.31-1.6.amzn1.x86_64 providing httpd is already installed"]}
ok: [172.31.5.165] => {"changed": false, "msg": "", "rc": 0, "results": ["httpd-2.2.31-1.6.amzn1.x86_64 providing httpd is already installed"]}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
172.31.24.166              : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
172.31.5.165               : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Here is me looking for httpd:

```
root@ip-172-31-5-165 ~]# yum list installed httpd
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Any help would be great~ Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

> connection: local

What you are doing is [delegating these tasks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks) to all run locally on the system that Ansible is running on, rather than running on the target hosts. That's why Apache isn't being installed on the target systems.

Also, the `dest` parameter in the copy task is a full path to a file, not just a path.  So if you want to copy a file called foo.txt then you need to do something like this:

```
- name: copy foo.txt
  copy: src=/path/to/source/foo.txt dest=/path/to/target/foo.txt
```

FYI, you will likely also want to do this once you get the yum task working:

```
- name: ensure apache is started
  service: name=httpd enabled=true state=started
```

This task will ensure that apache is started and is also set to start up automatically if/when the server is rebooted.

Comment: Jez its obvious when you say it like that :) Thanks Bruce, that did the trick for both. Yes I do plan on having a few more Tasks now that you got me working, and starting apache is one of them. Thanks again~ Cheers~